# How to do selection sorting

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

I have the following data that needs to be sorted using selection sort. We have itemName, category, quantity and price as instance variables.

```
“Blouse” “W” 21 17.95
“Blouse” “C” 35 17.95
“Shirt”  “M” 13 21.95
“Pants”  “W” 22 67.95
“Pants”  “M” 22 62.95
“Pants”  “C” 26 21.95
“Coat”   “C” 20 21.95
“Coat”   “M” 10 62.95
```

Here is my code for selection sort but my output isn't coming out right. When it is supposed to display in ascending order it displays in descending order. what should I do? is my problem in my compare to method or on the code below?

```
int min;
Comparable temp;
for(int index = 0; index< list.length-1; index++)
{
    min=index;
    for(int scan= index+1; scan<list.length; scan++)
    {
        if(list[min].compareTo(list[scan])<0)
            min = scan;
        temp= list[min];
        list[min] = list[index];
        list[index]= temp;
```

Comment: Sounds like a home work question.  Try a [Google search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) first.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wrote your code like this (the way you posted doesn't sort at all):

```
    int min;
    Comparable temp;
    for(int index = 0; index< list.length-1; index++)
    {
        min=index;
        for(int scan= index+1; scan<list.length; scan++)
        {
            if(list[min].compareTo(list[scan])<0)
                min = scan;
        }

        temp= list[index];
        list[index] = list[min];
        list[min]= temp;            
    }
```

All you need to change is this line `if(list[min].compareTo(list[scan])<0)`

To this `if(list[min].compareTo(list[scan])>0)`

Changing to the `>` operand will sort your list in `ascending` order.